# Is my webcam driver being used to hack my computer?

Tags: arch-linux, security

I'm seeing this in the journal:

```
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'TOSHIBA Web Camera'
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) TOSHIBA Web Camera: always reports core events
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera: Device: "/dev/input/event12"
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (--) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera: Vendor 0xbda Product 0x58e5
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (--) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera: Found keys
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (II) evdev: TOSHIBA Web Camera: Configuring as keyboard
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.5/3-1.5:1.0/input/input15/event12"
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "TOSHIBA Web Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc104"
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "mt,fr,gb"
Mar 27 14:01:02 user-PC gdm-Xorg-:0[424]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ",oss,"
```

Why is a Webcam being configured as a keyboard (see 6th line above)? Is my system hacked? Is someone using my Webcam driver to pass commands to my PC?

Comment: At a guess, the "keys" it found are whatever control buttons that particular brand of webcam comes with, so Xorg registers them as a keyboard-type interface so it'll know how to handle the buttonpress events.

Comment: It is a built-in webcam without any physical buttons.

Comment: You are not hacked. See the above comment, at least there is functional key to on/off the camera.

Comment: If you are annoyed enough with your webcam story - put duct tape over your webcam if you're not using it - http://www.reddit.com/r/nosleep/comments/1w9llu/psa_put_duct_tape_over_your_webcam_if_youre_not/

Comment: There are no Fn  +F? key combinations to turn off webcam on my laptop but thanks for your comments.